# Why is IntelliJ IDEA showing two "Gradle" options in the import Project dialog?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I try to import an exisiting project into IntelliJ IDEA, it presents me with this dialog:

[image: screenshot showing two "Gradle" entries in "Import Project" dialog]

Note that there are *two* Gradle options.

It only started doing this recently. (I first noticed today, and I'm sure it wasn't doing it a month or two ago.)

1. How do I find out what the difference is between these options (if any)?
2. How can I remove the redundant Gradle option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20648) related to `build.gradle.kts` Kotlin build files. The bug is already fixed, wait for the next update.

Comment: The best help Support Lead at JetBrains :P